# How can I run GoogleNet or Inception5H model on my data, to get output of accuracies of the models? For example like contingency table

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

This is my code to basically test the model on my data, but its just making images and concepts of the data. Is there a way or something to get an output of the accuracies of those concepts(models) like in a contingency table?

```
%run ace_run.py --target_class LSP --source_dir 'tcav/tcav_examples/image_models/imagenet/YOUR_FOLDER/' --working_dir SAVE_DIR --model_to_run GoogleNet --model_path 'tcav/tcav_examples/image_models/imagenet/YOUR_FOLDER/inception5h/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb' --labels_path ./imagenet_labels.txt --bottlenecks mixed4c --num_random_exp 10 --max_imgs 10 --min_imgs 9
```

[results of the above code, concept examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I9Pw.png)

I tought that the model will automatically get me results of the accuracies, but it didnt work. So I need a way to get accuracies of the model in contingency table or other options.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The above code is running a model on my data to basically classify those images, but that code is not giving me the accuracy or precision of the model.